# Printing spare plastic parts

Tags: scanning

A small [7 cm long x 5 cm high x 10 cm deep] hard plastic piece of my old luggage broke (see attached). The manufacturer does not have spares for this old model.

[image: Broken part of luggage]

Is there any way to scan the working piece on the left with an Android app and order a 3D printed one-off one?

Comment: For a simple part like that I'd say it would be easier to just draw the part in CAD from scratch than to deal with all the hassle of 3d scanning.

Comment: @floppydisk Please make this an answer! This is exactly what I was thinking as well. Having worked with dedicated 3D scanners I know that after scanning you frequently need to redraw or edit the parts anyways as not always the part comes out fine.

Comment: IMHO, it would be better to clone the left one with silicone caulk and cornstarch to make a negative mould, then use epoxy to fill the mold and create the positive. You can stain the epoxy with a bit of charcoal dust to make it black. Lots of 3D printing has also taught me that simpler methods are often, well, simpler.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the comments!! I am just thinking, is there any possible way to get this for less than... say, $40 USD? Because all this sounds very advanced to me. I wonder if I can scan the piece, share it with some 3d printers online and get it for some reasonable price.

Comment: Create a model and find someone with a printer in your vincinity; there are probably open printer networks or maker spaces you can use nearby or through mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used some thermoplastic. It does not look exactly like the original as I had to give it shape with my own hands, but certainly does the trick. It also costs less than $10 USD. Let's see how long it lasts.

[image: Fixed suitcase]

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely could try using [Polycam](https://poly.cam/) to try to scan the piece on the left, and then create a model from it.  That's not "plug-and-play" though - would take some modeling prowess to get it to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 3d scanning would be practical here since this is a small and very simple part. [You can model it using reference pictures in Fusion360 instead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLso-cx9vyA). The program is free for personal use too. Plus learning how to do this means you can start fixing other stuff on your house using the same method later.